# how can i automatically record every terminal session?

Tags: shell, history, logs, typescript

I like to use tools like `history`, `script`, and `asciinema` to record and review xterm (i.e. `bash`/`sh`) sessions for typical, general administration reasons, and also, sometimes for comprehensive study/revision; as a learning tool.

- I thought of setting the default `$SHELL` as a direct path to said tools and/or commands, like:

  - `/bin/script transcript.log;`
  - `/bin/asciinema rec -w0.5 term_log.json;`
- But these tools typically rely on having a default `$SHELL` set (i.e. `/bin/bash`, `/bin/sh`, `/bin/zsh`, etc.).
- Also, I feel like re-defining system variables (i.e. `$SHELL`, `$TERM`, etc.) or trying to get it working with config (`*.conf`) and dot (`~/.bashrc` / `~/.bash_profile`) files is gona be riddled with all kinds of holes and potential problems.
- However, every time I decide or realize that I want a transcript of a session, it's after the fact, or I'll be halfway through the interesting part already, or some such scenario.

What's the correct, or best practice to set something like this up to simply log everything (preferably `stdin`, `stdout` (and `stderr` when applicable), etc.) automatically?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but I use GNU screen with a large buffer size and then "hardcopy -h filename" when I realize something interesting has just scrolled by too fast. Also, despite, your hesitance, experiment with putting "script" or something into .login .profile .bash_profile or similar.

Comment: @barrycarter Maybe if I could get it to save to a new file every time. Maybe I could just use something like `"$(date)"` for the transcript name..

Comment: I was thinking something like that too. In my own crontab, I have things like "cp /var/tmp/mesoapi.txt \`/bin/date +\%Y\%m\%d.\%H\%M\%S.\%N\`". Just be careful with escaping the % signs, they can be tricky.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this in your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` might work for you:

```
if test -t 0 -a -t 1 -a -z "$SCRIPTING"
then
    export SCRIPTING="$HOME/.script.$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S).$$)"
    exec script "$SCRIPTING"
fi
```